# Display availability in add to cart button for WooCommerce simple products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-quantity

I have this code which works if I remove the else if part of it, but if doing that, it will show BUY NOW (0 AVAILABLE) when out of stock.

I need it to say SOLD OUT when out of stock. Here's the code I'm using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'atc_with_qty', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'atc_with_qty', 10, 2 );
function atc_with_qty( $add_to_cart_button_text, $product ) {

    $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        $add_to_cart_button_text = __('Buy Now ('.$stock.' Available)', 'woocommerce');
    return $add_to_cart_button_text;

    } else if ( !$product->is_in_stock() && $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        $add_to_cart_button_text = __('SOLD OUT', 'woocommerce');

        return $add_to_cart_button_text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** Your elseif condition, never matches… Try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'add_to_cart_text_availability', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'add_to_cart_text_availability', 10, 2 );
function add_to_cart_text_availability( $add_to_cart_text, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            $add_to_cart_text = sprintf( 
                __("Buy Now (%s Available)", "woocommerce"), 
                $product->get_stock_quantity() 
            );
        } else {
            $add_to_cart_text = __('SOLD OUT', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $add_to_cart_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: that broke all buttons.

Comment: @KevinAronsson I have updated the answer (I was finishing my code) and it doesn't broke anything now .